flutter web app is causing unwanted navigations when resizing the window
When I am trying to resize the window of any screen, its getting back to the previous screen
Is it because of  the large size of application that is causing unwanted navigations or is it the use of layout builder which I am using in every screen as the parent of scaffold
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    print('MediaQuery size: ${MediaQuery.of(context).size}');
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size != mq) {
      print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++');
      setState(() {
        mq = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      });
    }
  }`

I tried to debug and for that I used didChangeDependencies() method
still can't find the reason for unwanted back navigations

It's impossible to tell without seeing the full code. My guess is that you are doing some logic inside a build method or inside a builder that you aren't supposed to do. In general you wouldn't want to execute code there that might mess things up when called more than once. I think it's a common mistake that people put such code there. You should implement build methods in such a way that it shouldn't matter how often it is called because you can't rely on it being only called once
